# Visual Studio Remote Debugging : how to keep the remote terminal window open at the end of execution?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, terminal, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2019 for C/C++ development, and have setup the Remote Windows Debugger by following [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-cpp?view=vs-2019). It works fine, but I would like a feature and I can't find how to activate it.

When debugging locally, the program is executed using the "Microsoft Visual Studio Debug Console", which allows to stay open while displaying the exit code at the end of execution :

```
<program>.exe (process 2020) exited with code 1.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

I would like to have the same behavior when debugging remotely, but on the remote computer the program is executed with the regular Command Prompt, which does not offer this feature. I couldn't find how to do it by googling it.

Is it at all possible to keep the remote terminal open at the end of execution ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did some tests, and it seems this is by design and there is no option to keep the remote terminal window open at the end of execution.

This maybe doesn't meet your requirements, but perhaps you can try to add this code line as a work around:

```
system("pause");
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this workaround does not work for me, as I use `exit()` statements in several places of the program.

Comment: @SuperBoby, I see, then there is no option to change to meet your requirement if not from code sides. If you really want this feature, you can suggest this feature to Visual Studio Product Team on [Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=suggestion).